# do i need to install sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Do i need to install sqlite for android or its already installed while installing all the plugin. I was trying to run the application [MJAndroid, example in O'Reilly book](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521509/) but i am getting error in the file where the application is trying to extend SQLiteCursor Class.

**EDIT**

This is the [Error Tree](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/2760/capturerd.png).. I am an absolute beginner to android

**EDIT2**

@CommonsWare thanks for the links. I tried those links and now its giving a new error ie:

```
     The type R is already defined
```

[Screen shot](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/5954/captureuf.png)

aanybody pls explain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SQLite is part of the standard Android library; its classes can be found in [android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).  You don't need to install it.

What is the error you are getting when extending SQLiteCursor?

Answer (score 2):

Look at:

http://www.javakb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/java-tools/2404/Eclipse-cannot-find-java-lang-Enum

and:

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t108476.html

for advice on your `java.lang.Enum` import problem. You might also want to take a closer look at the first error, which suggests your build path is messed up.